# Python Tuples: remove the first three elements cleanly

Tags: python, tuples

My issues:

- How is `(9,)` different from `(9)`?  `(9,)==(9)` yields `False`
- Why is `(9,)` showing up in the snippet below?
- How do I fix the code below so I get `(9)`?

```
chop_first_three = lambda t: t[3:]
chop_first_three((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))  # (4, 5) correct
chop_first_three(('abc', 7, 8, 9)) # (9,)   ??? why not (9)?
```

### Answer

The simple answer is, parentheses are overloaded for grouping and for tuples.  To differentiate these forms in python, a trailing comma explicitly indicates a tuple.

Several answers and comments below point this out.

I've left my original questions above so the answers below make sense, but obviously, some of my original questions were incorrect.

Comment: (9,) is a tuple with one item in it. (9) is simply the number 9 (which is an integer).

That's why the equality check returns false

Comment: Oh, wow - it totally slipped my mind that parentheses are overloaded.  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python if you wrap an object in parenthesis you will just get the element back.

```py
a = (9)
print(type(a)) # <class 'int'>
```

`(9,)` instead is a tuple containing only one element (the number 9)

```py
a = (9,)
print(type(a)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

When you slice a tuple you will always get a tuple back (even if it only contains one element) Therefore the `(9,)`

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses with no commas in them are for grouping operations, so `(9)` is just a strange way to say `9`.

It seems strange here, but it's important for reasonable things like `(4 + 5) * 6`:

- Without the parentheses, PEMDAS would evaluate `5 * 6` first, and you'd get the wrong answer (`34` instead of `54`).
- With the parentheses, if you didn't need a comma to be a `tuple`, that would evaluate to a one-`tuple` containing `9`, which sequence multiplication would expand to `(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)`, again, not what you wanted.

So specifically for the case of one-`tuple`s, the trailing comma says "I'm making a `tuple`, not just grouping operations". You can include a trailing comma in any `tuple`, but it's mandatory for one-`tuple`s.

In short, the result you're seeing is correct. If you really hate the trailing comma, it's on you to manually format your `tuple`s so it doesn't contain them when it comes time to `print`/stringify them. For example, given a `tuple` that might have only one element, you can do:

```
maybe_one_tuple = ...
comma_sep = ', '.join(map(str, maybe_one_tuple))
with_parens = f'({comma_sep})'
print(with_parens)
```

Or a cheesy trick to use the stringified form of `list` to reduce the custom work you need to do yourself:

```
list_str_form = str(list(maybe_one_tuple))
with_parens = f'({list_str_form[1:-1]})'
```

which just converts to `list`, stringifies the `list` (which is the same string form as `tuple` except with `[]` instead of `()`, and with no trailing comma needed for length one `list`s), manually strip the guaranteed to exist `[` and `]` and replaces them with `(` and `)`.

Answer (score -4):

Python tuples is immutable, so that , you can't change any items in tuples.

If you want to change tuples items then convert tuples into list and then modified and change into tuples..

Thank you .

This is my first comment

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's problem. It's perfectly possible to make modified copies of a `tuple`, which is what the OP is doing, and their question isn't asking about in-place mutations.